# bigquery - specifying service account file

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a service account .json file and I'd like to use it to run queries.

From `bq --help` it would appear that the flag / param is `--service-account-credential-file <file>` but when I use this:

`bq query --service-account-credential-file <file> "some query"`

I get this error:

**FATAL Flags parsing error: Unknown command line flag 'service-account-credential-file'**

Wrong order? Wrong flag? Not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get:

```
Unknown command line flag 'service-account-credential-file'. Did you mean: service_account_credential_file?
```

So it sounds like you need to do:

```
bq query --service_account_credential_file <file> "some query"
```

Comment: this is now [DEPRECATED](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#expandable-1)